# jQuery: How to apply an effect to an element that shares a name with other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write some code where a description box pops over an image when I hover over it. I have multiple images on my page which sort of looks like this:

```
<div class="image">
    <a href="?page=page1>"><img src="images/1.jpg" width="220" height="220"></a>
</div>
<div class="description" style="display: none;"> description 1 </div>

<div class="image">
    <a href="?page=page2>"><img src="images/2.jpg" width="220" height="220"></a>
</div>
<div class="description" style="display: none;"> description 2 </div>

<div class="image">
    <a href="?page=page3"><img src="images/3.jpg" width="220" height="220"></a>
</div>
<div class="description" style="display: none;"> description 3 </div>
```

I am not very well versed in jQuery or Javascript but I have come up with this code that displays the description when ever you hover over the image:

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
    $(".description").fadeToggle();
});
```

The problem with this code is that when you over over any of the images, ALL of the description pop up. What must I add in to my jQuery code so that only the description of the image you are hover over pops up?

I have created a jsfiddle to help understand my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/qnWpy/
(also the description blinks erratically when I hover over or around the image, why's that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
    $(this).next(".description").fadeToggle();
});
```

Use the next() function; http://api.jquery.com/next/

Updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qnWpy/1/

FYI, $(this) refers to the currently selected element.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This code is working for me but I have a small bug. The .description class actually has a negative margin-top so it displays on top of the image. When ever I hover over the image the .description class shows up but if my mouse happens to be over the . description class the class disappears again. Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/zakiaziz/qnWpy/2/

Answer (score 1):

Try selecting the description relative to the hovered element.

```
$(".image").hover(function() {
    $(this).next(".description").fadeToggle();
});
```

the ".description" isn't required here, but may prevent bugs later

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. This code does work but I have a small bug. The .description class actually has a negative margin-top so it displays on top of the image. When ever I hover over the image the .description class shows up but if my mouse happens to be over the . description class the class disappears again. Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/zakiaziz/qnWpy/2